# \num[round-mode=figures,round-precision=#2] is not a number that can be used by \fp_eval:n

Tags: siunitx, expl3

Sometimes I want/have to break a calculation into a series of steps because I have a term that I want to use in a future calculation, but because significant figures matters, I need to adjust the number.

While not the most realistic, my MWE demonstrates that my efforts to use a `expl3` function `\fp_eval:n` to evaluate a mathematical expression can't use the `siunitx` rounded result as a future input.

Example: 
Rather than use the full quadratic formula, lets break it into two cumulative terms to show the effect of significant figure precision loss: i.e. instead of evaluating the whole expression at once in memory, lets break it into `X1 = T1 + T2` or `X2 = T1 - T2` where `T1` and `T2` have already been evaluated and reduced to the illustrative significant figures.

I have no problems using my function to solve for `T1` and `T2`, but using `T1` and `T2` in the calculations for `X1` and `X2` fails.

The combined `fp_eval`, `\num`, and `newcommand` for evaulation, rounding, and storage (for continued use), repectively, is in the MWE below, however I can't successfully call the second round of `MyEval` commands without generating what I interpret to be `not a number` errors.

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}


%\ExplSyntaxOn
%   \cs_set_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
%\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewDocumentCommand {\MyEval} {m O{6} m}
    {
        \newcommand{#1}{
            \num[round-mode=figures,round-precision=#2]{\fp_eval:n {#3}}
        }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\MySF}{6}

%\newcommand{\MyEval}[2]{%
%   \newcommand{#1}{%
%       \num[round-mode=figures,round-precision=4]{%
%           \fpeval{#2}%
%       }%
%   }%
%}%

\begin{document}\noindent   

\textbf{Quadratic Equation}: $x^2 + 40x + 2 = 0$ 

\renewcommand{\MySF}{4}

\newcommand{\qa}{1}
\newcommand{\qb}{40}
\newcommand{\qc}{2}

%\MyEval{\QuadraticxOne}[\MySF]{(1/2)*(1/\qa)*(-\qb + ((\qb)^2-(4*\qa*\qc))^(1/2))}
%\MyEval{\QuadraticxTwo}[\MySF]{(1/2)*(1/\qa)*(-\qb - ((\qb)^2-(4*\qa*\qc))^(1/2))}

\MyEval{\QuadratictOne}[\MySF]{(1/2)*(1/\qa)*(-\qb)}
\MyEval{\QuadratictTwo}[\MySF]{(1/2)*(1/\qa)*(((\qb)^2-(4*\qa*\qc))^(1/2))}

\MyEval{\QuadraticxOne}[\MySF]{\QuadratictOne+\QuadratictTwo}
\MyEval{\QuadraticxTwo}[\MySF]{\QuadratictOne-\QuadratictTwo}

    \begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
        t_1 = \QuadratictOne\\
        t_2 = \QuadratictTwo\\
        %x_1 = \QuadraticxOne\\
        %x_2 = \QuadraticxTwo\\
    \end{aligned} \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`\num` is a command for *printing* numbers, not for manipulating them. The floating point operations include `round`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand {\MyEval} {m O{6} m}
 {
  \tl_new:N #1
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { \fp_eval:n { round( (#3) , #2 ) } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\MySF}{6}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Quadratic Equation}: $x^2 + 40x + 2 = 0$ 

\renewcommand{\MySF}{4}

\newcommand{\qa}{1}
\newcommand{\qb}{40}
\newcommand{\qc}{2}

\MyEval{\QuadratictOne}[\MySF]{(1/2)*(1/\qa)*(-\qb)}
\MyEval{\QuadratictTwo}[\MySF]{(1/2)*(1/\qa)*(((\qb)^2-(4*\qa*\qc))^(1/2))}

\MyEval{\QuadraticxOne}[\MySF]{\QuadratictOne+\QuadratictTwo}
\MyEval{\QuadraticxTwo}[\MySF]{\QuadratictOne-\QuadratictTwo}

\begin{align*}
t_1 &= \QuadratictOne\\
t_2 &= \QuadratictTwo\\
x_1 &= \QuadraticxOne\\
x_2 &= \QuadraticxTwo
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Note that I say `\tl_set:Nx` so the evaluation is performed fully.

[image]

### New version after comments

You need to detach the computation step from the printing step.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand {\MyEval} {mm}
 {
  \tl_new:N #1
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { \fp_eval:n { #2 } }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyNum}{O{6}m}
 {
  \num[round-mode=figures,round-precision=#1]{#2}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\MySF}{6}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Quadratic Equation}: $x^2 + 40x + 2 = 0$ 

\renewcommand{\MySF}{4}

\newcommand{\qa}{1}
\newcommand{\qb}{40}
\newcommand{\qc}{2}

\MyEval{\QuadratictOne}{(1/2)*(1/\qa)*(-\qb)}
\MyEval{\QuadratictTwo}{(1/2)*(1/\qa)*(((\qb)^2-(4*\qa*\qc))^(1/2))}

\MyEval{\QuadraticxOne}{\QuadratictOne+\QuadratictTwo}
\MyEval{\QuadraticxTwo}{\QuadratictOne-\QuadratictTwo}

\begin{align*}
t_1 &= \MyNum{\QuadratictOne}\\
t_2 &= \MyNum{\QuadratictTwo}\\
x_1 &= \MyNum[\MySF]{\QuadraticxOne}\\
x_2 &= \MyNum[\MySF]{\QuadraticxTwo}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation about printing.  Is there no `parse` function? I was aware of round, but I was using `siunitx` because I needed significant figures instead, a function I do not believe is currently available in the floating point operators of `expl3`

Comment: @EngBIRD You mean with padding 0's? When you *print* the result you use `\num`.

Comment: For example, using `t2, x1, and x2` from the screen shot still visible on my screen from the comment window, I have 4 digit precision in rounding, but variable (6, 3, and 6, respectively) digit precision from significant figures.  As far as I know, the first zero right of the decimal in `0.0501` does not count as a significant figure.  So I don't think it's `padding 0's` that I'm trying to accommodate if we're on the same page about what a `padding 0 is`.

Comment: @EngBIRD I added a new version

Comment: I'm really sorry, but this won't work either.  The point of breaking up the calculation is so that `\QuadratictOne or Two` is not left in memory with all a full floating point precision prior to being used to solve for `QuadraticxOne or Two`.  Properly solved, with significant figures, `-20 + 19.95 = -0.05 not 00.05006` (i.e. 19.9499 can't be used in place of 19.95 just because it's more precise).  I guess you could say that for the purpose of this document, I have to propagate rounding "errors".

Comment: @EngBIRD No, *properly* solving should use the full floating capabilities. If you want to do wrong math, do it yourself. `;-)`

Comment: Hahahaha, I saw this coming.  I'm a little surprised though, limiting uncertainty through error propagation and significant figures is common practice in physics.  I will however have to defer to the TeX genius and career mathematician!

Answer (score 1):

So without `siunitx` I can numerically process a value to SDF significant figures using:

> ROUND(value,SDF-(1+INT(LOG10(ABS(value)))))

Additionally, it's useful to be able to reuse and update calculations, so in order for calculations of the same variable to be updated gradually I've added a check (`\cs_if_exist:NF #1 {\tl_new:N #1}`) to determine if the command already exists to prevent errors stating document command already exists.

So the MWE becomes

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand {\MySFRound} {m O{6} m}
 {
     \cs_if_exist:NF #1 {\tl_new:N #1}
     \tl_set:Nx #1 { \fp_eval:n {  round( (#3) , (#2 - (1 + floor(ln(abs(#3))/ln(10)))) ) } }
     %ROUND(value,SDF-(1+INT(LOG10(ABS(value)))))
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\MySF}{6}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Quadratic Equation}: $x^2 + 40x + 2 = 0$ 

\renewcommand{\MySF}{4}

\newcommand{\qa}{1}
\newcommand{\qb}{40}
\newcommand{\qc}{2}

\MySFRound{\QuadratictOne}[\MySF]{(1/2)*(1/\qa)*(-\qb)}
\MySFRound{\QuadratictTwo}[\MySF]{(1/2)*(1/\qa)*(((\qb)^2-(4*\qa*\qc))^(1/2))}

\MySFRound{\QuadraticxOne}[\MySF]{\QuadratictOne+\QuadratictTwo}
\MySFRound{\QuadraticxTwo}[\MySF]{\QuadratictOne-\QuadratictTwo}

\begin{align*}
t_1 &= \QuadratictOne\\
t_2 &= \QuadratictTwo\\
x_1 &= \QuadraticxOne\\
x_2 &= \QuadraticxTwo
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Note:  Until logs of arbitrary bases are implemented, you can use `ln(X)/ln(10)` to solve for `log_10(X)` ([logarithms in expl3 math functions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338827/logarithms-in-expl3-math-functions?noredirect=1#comment831122_338827))