# logarithms in expl3 math functions

Tags: expl3

The only reference to `log` functions I've found in the  `expl3` documentation refers to diagnostic type function recording, however, I would like to ask about the mathematical log functions.

The following MWE comes from an existing question showing the capabilities of trig functions to be parsed by a numerical `expl3` internal function.

Is there a notation that `expl3`can use to parse logs of different bases?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% make an internal function available to the user
\cs_set_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\cos(\pi)=\fpeval{cos(pi)}$

$\sin(\pi/3)=\fpeval{sin(pi/3)}$

$\sin(\pi/3)=\fpeval{round(sin(pi/3),3)}$

%$\log(100)=\fpeval{round(log(100),10)}$ % this doesn't work, neither does log10

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is in Bruno's 'to do' list in the docs: at present you have to use `ln` and covert bases in-place, I think (`round(ln(100)/ln(10))`).

Comment: But first we need to sort random numbers ...

Comment: @JosephWright Isn't having them unsorted the point?

Comment: @JosephWright Does `fpeval` have the ability to do exponential operations:  i.e. provide a base and exponent value?  trying this out, \fpeval doesn't like `^` operators and `pow(base,exp)` is similarly unrecognized.

Comment: @EngBIRD `\fp_eval:n` is fine with `^`: I'll need an example to suggest why it's not for you